# How to count the number of records on the base of groups in SSRS tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

following is the structure of my report.

```
                Value1     Value2     Value3
 Group 1      
                  11         22         33
 Group 2      
                  22         32         43
```

Now I want to count the number of groups not the total number of records.
I want an expression that will return in the following manner.

```
Selected Records: 2
```

Please give your kind suggestion to accomplish the above probelm.

Answer (score 0):

An expression like this in a table header row would accomplish this:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Group.Value)
```

The `CountDistinct` aggregate expression just counts all the different non-null values in a scope - by applying this in a table header row this will check all rows in the table/Dataset.

If you want to add the string into the same expression use something like:

```
="Selected Records: " & CountDistinct(Fields!Group.Value)
```